# PHP & MYSQL blank result. Script suddenly stops. No errorlog

Tags: php, mysql

I want to wrtite a simple code that lets me download a file depending on the ID specified in the URL. For doing that, it connects to the database and tries to get the information of the file associated to the ID. Then, it sends the headers with the extracted info and the file.

But for reasons that I don't know, it outputs a blank page. There aren't any logfiles anywhere, just it suddenly stops.

Please, a bit of help would be really appreciated. Thanks you for spending your time

```
<?php
//We include the variables needed to do the connection to the db
include '../php/vars.php';
$id=$_GET['id'];

//We connect to the database
$con = mysql_connect("$dbsv","$dbuser","$dbpass");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("$dbname", $con);

// We do the query
if ($query === false) {echo mysql_error();}
$query = "SELECT name,filetype FROM links WHERE id=$id";
$result = mysql_query($query);


// Check result. This shows the actual query sent to MySQL, and the error. Useful for debugging.
if (!$result) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
    die($message);
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{

// Assign variables
    $filename = $row['name'];
    $type = $row['filetype'];

}


//We download the file
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header( "Content-type: $type"); 
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($filename));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
    fopen("$filename", "r");;
   exit;
}
?>
```

I'm not native English. Expect gramatical, syntax and ortographical errors. If you detect them, please, notify me.

Comment: At the bottom you have a syntax error: `fopen("$filename", "r");;` delete the semicolon at the end

Comment: @Bluedayz that's not a syntax error. `;` delimtes any statement - and the "empty" Character is a valid statement. In other words: it doesn't matter :)

Comment: `readfile($filename); //fopen("$filename", "r");` fopen does not do what you expect, use readfile

Comment: use mysqli, mysql_* is deprecated

Comment: Or you consider using PDO, also a great choice

Comment: Thank you for helping. I would like to use mysqli but i can't because of my host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see you want to pass the file right?

```
fopen("$filename", "r");
```

replace this with

```
readfile($filename);
```

fopen just opens a file pointer and does absolutly nothing with the file itself, you have to use fread, write and fclose to do stuff with the file, there are more operations but basicly fopen just gives you a file pointer

Comment: `file_get_contents` will also do nothing unless you use the return value, eg `echo file_get_contents($filename);`

Comment: For large file using fread would be better, cause it will start outputing content after finishing the first chunk. `file_get_contents` blocks until the whole file is loaded into the memory.

Comment: yeah right actually I meant readfile, I am a bit dizzy. - updated

Comment: I've changed 'fopen' for 'readfile' and it worked like a charm :D. Thank you very much!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of logical errors, you need to fix:

```
if ($query === false) {echo mysql_error();}
```

`$query` is not set at this point. so it's never `false`. (You are saying basically `if (null === false)`)

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{

// Assign variables
    $filename = $row['name'];
    $type = $row['filetype'];

}


//We download the file
if (file_exists($filename)) {
```

Depending on your result count you are overriding `$filename` multiple times - and then only perform an operation on the LAST value.

- Either move the logic into the `while` loop.
- Or don't use a while-loop if you are expecting a single result.

Then:

```
fopen("$filename", "r");
```

You are opening a file - and then? doing nothing at all. Continue with `fread()` until `EOF` is reached and then use `fclose($handle)` bevor outputting the result. 
(*This is the reason for simply seeing nothing*)

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky no, it's `null`. Therefore performing a check with `==` will be true - but not with `===`. See: `if ($a == false) echo "a is false"; if ($b === false) echo "b is false";` First condition will be true, last one not.

Comment: I tried removing the while loop, but it stops working, so I think I'm going to leave it intact.

Answer (score 0):

You would use readfile() instead. readfile() reads a file and writes it to the output buffer.

Here is manual link http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

```
if (file_exists($filename)) { 
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header( "Content-type: $type"); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($filename));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
readfile($filename);
exit;
}
```